# PDF ломается при загрузке в ЛК налоговой

Tags: кодировка, symfony, pdf, dompdf

Есть приложение на Symfony, которое создает PDF документы для пользователей через dompdf. При загрузке в ЛК налоговой возникает проблема и документ ломается. Ни в каких других приложениях такое отображение не встречается.

Судя по всему проблема даже не с кодировкой. Мне не понять даже, как описать проблему на скрине:) Видно, что сломался не только текст, но HTML под ним. Что это может значить вообще?

[image: Отображение PDF в ЛК налоговой]

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=pdf+embed+fonts. Вы воспользовались каким-то экзотическим шрифтом, которого нет на целевой системе.

Comment: Похоже на проблему с используемыми шрифтами, этот просмотрщик не может их отобразить, либо их у него нет.